# Multivariable Calculus Integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm refreshing myself with multivariate calculus and I came across this problem:

Calculate the area of the region bounded by $\sqrt x + \sqrt y = \sqrt a$ and $\ x + \ y = \ a$.

I was just wondering how to find the limits of integration given this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the equations up to each other to find their points of contact.

$\sqrt x + \sqrt y = \sqrt a$

Squaring both sides...

$x+2\sqrt{xy}+y=a$

$x+2\sqrt{xy}+y=x^2+y^2$

Set the integrals up from the two equations' $x$ (coordinate)point(s) of contact.

Comment: Would that be x is between 0 and a?

Comment: I got it- I integrated y between $ \ a-x $ and $ \sqrt a - \sqrt x $ and x between 0 and a and got  $ \ 1/a^2 $ which is the right answer. Thank you very much!